# closing a window in top right corner button without exiting the system java descktop applications

Tags: java

hi guys my question is about closing a child window in top right corner without exiting the system any idea

[image]

i want it to do something like `despose();` with a pushbutton
thanx in advance

Comment: [tag:Swing] or [tag:javafx]?

Comment: Is [Default Close Operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) what you are looking for?

Comment: yes i am using swing.. in properties i set Default Close Operation  to dispose but it exit all the system when i close on top right corner!  i want the child frame to be closed without closing parent or exiting all the application!

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this is what you mean but if you mean to move the x button then you have to make the frame that you have a jpanel rather than a jframe or anything and then when your done with that make a jbutton and place it on the top and when your done doning that design it and then add a action listener to the button when that action listener knows that the button was clicked then do f.dispose(); and that will close it :D

Comment: no i did not mean that ... what i mean is to close a child window in top right corner (X) without exiting all the program..

Comment: well then you can use multiple frames and then close the different variables but ive never worked with child windows so sorry :(